# Define detected Object width with SURF in OpenCV

Tags: object, opencv, detection, surf, homography

i am working under a robotic project. Exactly with object detect with SURF on opencv. I found many codes on the net of objects detection. What i didn't found exactly is the width of the object in the image and the coordinates of its corners?

And, is is possible to define the distance of the object to the cam?

any help will be very appreciated

Comment: if you only have one image, the best you can do is map points on the object in the image to rays in world space.  Both the z cord of the object and its size are undefined (their ratio is defined).  If you know ahead of time how large the object is you can find its distance assuming you have a calibrated camera

Comment: thanks, it's nice.. i don't know how to calibrate the camera and on what that can help me?

Comment: opencv can help, you can see the relevant functions [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) there are a variety of tutorials on the internet

Comment: if i want to catch a cup with a robot arm that has 2 cams, how do i proceed then, i am newbie: (

Comment: that is a big question.  You should proceed by attempting easier things first.  I would assume you need to recognize the cup, estimate its position, and then find a grabbing method, none of which are easy.  [this](http://szeliski.org/Book/) helped me out a lot when I started.  Good luck

Comment: thanks, i have to recognize the cup with SURF or SIFT (this what is asked from me). The first camera is on the arm, so i need to know first its size and it's postion (with calibration), isn't it like this?
can you telle me what do u mean by grabbing method?

Comment: I was assuming there must be some options in how you grab the cup.  I don't know anything about your problem though.  You need to make your question much clearer if you want help.

Comment: Yeah i should explain more my question but i'm really gratefull for the effort you've done for me.
Ok, in fact: based on a video and a capture from it i wanted to execute the famous code of detecting objects:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/983/object-detection-using-surf-flann/[/link]

So, i have to see the baby recognized and in a rectangle but, the problem here http://postimage.org/image/94jney73x/, you see that the rectangle is bigger than what it supposed to be.

Comment: as it stands your question is not clear or complete enough for me or anyone else to give you much help sorry.